# What is difference between $(document) and $('*') and how to make sure $ reference is assigned to which library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I understand it as: `$(document)` will have whole `DOM` of the current page like `document`, while `$('*')` also selects whole DOM, then what's the difference between them, aren't they are same ?

Will not `$` assignment of different libraries will conflict, how they are assigned ?

Comment: Are you asking what the `$` is? It's just a short hand for jQuery.

Comment: `$(document)` is the document object wrapped in a jquery wrapper, `$('*')` says to jquery select everything. They are totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` in jQuery is basically Syntatic Sugar which means developers love to assign `$` as shorthand for different library. In this case `$` is shorthand of `jQuery` or `window.jQuery`.

jQuery can be run in compatibility mode if another library is already using `$`. Just use `jQuery.noConflict();` to know if there is. `$` is pretty commonly used as a selector function in various JavaScript libraries.

Run `jQuery.noConflict()` method to give control of the `$` variable back to whichever library first implemented it. This helps to make sure that jQuery doesn't conflict with the `$` object of other libraries.

Here is simple way of avoiding any conflict:

```
// Import other Library
// Import jQuery Library
$.noConflict();
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
```

This technique is especially effective in conjunction with the `.ready()` method's ability to alias the jQuery object, as within the `.ready()` we can use `$` if we wish without fear of conflicts later:

```
// Import other library
// Import jQuery
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
```

**As per jQuery documentation:**

> By default, jQuery uses "$" as shortcut for "jQuery"

having said that.

`$(".class_name")` or `jQuery(".class_name")` is the same.

Coming to next part of your question:

**What is `document` ?**

`document` is a Javascript internal DOM Object of the current webpage. In browser console you can go and invoke following:

> `document`
>   It will return you whole DOM of page in Tree format.

`> typeof(document)`

`<. object`

So, `typeof(document)` returned `object`. Hence, `document` is a DOM object containing whole webpage sourcecode + many additional information in tree format.

**What is `$(document)` ?**

Similarly, `$(document)` is also an Object, in Array format having `document` and `context` of webpage.

**What is `$('*')`?**

It is also an object returned after jQuery process full DOM. It contains array of all the elements in the DOM so that jQuery can process it faster and return result
You can try in browser console.

`> $('*')`

`> typeof($('*'))`

Comment: Also: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... })` can be reduced to `$(function () { ... })`.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document)` - the document object as in window.document, parsed for jQuery;

`$('*')` - an array that contains all the objects (tags) in the DOM, since '*' is a general selector for everything.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document)` will bring the object document which will contain the elements within it.

Where as `$('*')` will return an array of all elements